# I need to exclude the element in the list in for loop and update the xml file by searching with that excluded element using python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, skip

I need to exclude the element in the list in for loop and update the xml file by searching with that excluded element.

below is my xml file run.xml

```
<stm>
    <id>ignore</id>
    <ari>dv</rid>
    <session>test</session>
</stm>
```

I have a list `test = ['dv', 'ab', 'abc']`

```
for i in test:
    print i
    "here I need to exclude the current element(i) from the list(test)"
    "so the list will become for the first loop ['ab', 'abc']"
    "assign excluded list to variable"
    "next I need to search for current element(i) in the given xml file if found, update the next line 'test' with the 'temp'"
```

I have googled it but not found any related solutions

after updating the xml file, the output should look like

```
<stm>
    <id>ignore</id>
    <ari>dv</rid>
    <session>temp</session>
</stm>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a better way of going about what you are trying to do, but here are some ways of solving your problem:

if you want to create a list that has the excluded element for every element in your for loop:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in x:
...     l = [j for j in x if j !=i]
...     print(l)
...
[2, 3]
[1, 3]
[1, 2]
```

If you want to remove that value from the list forever:

```
>>> for i in x[:]:
...     #this is important to iterate over a copy of the whole list in case you remove elements that you want to use
...     x.remove(i)
...     print(x)
...
[2, 3]
[3]
[]
```

Hope this helps